# Why does this code pop into the same register twice after calling a function?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
push EAX
push 8
call malloc
pop EBX
pop EBX
mov [EAX], 0
mov [EAX+4], EBX
```

Why do we need to do pop EBX 2 times? What value(s) EBX will get each time?

Comment: It's balancing the stack by removing the two things pushed. It doesn't have to be `ebx` and it doesn't have to be a `pop` either. Normally you see `add esp, 8` but that's 3 bytes and this is just 2, so presumably optimizing for size.

Comment: Essentially the `8` that was pushed to the stack isn't needed any more once `malloc` is finished, and the easiest way to destroy it while maintaining stack alignment is to clobber it with the old value of `eax`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cardinal rule is, **whatever you push, you have to pop**. Otherwise, you'll unbalance the stack and cause the code to crash or worse. What that rule means is that you need to pop the same size (in bytes) worth of values that you pushed.

So in this case, you pushed 8 bytes on to the stack before calling malloc:

```
push EAX    ; push a DWORD-sized register (4 bytes)
push 8      ; push a DWORD immediate      (4 bytes)
```

To clean up the stack after the function call (required by `malloc`, since it uses the `cdecl` calling convention, which is caller-cleanup), you need to pop 8 bytes. It just so happens that a convenient way to do that is to pop a register-sized value twice:

```
pop EBX   ; pop 4 bytes
pop EBX   ; pop 4 bytes
```

The stack is [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).
The first pop puts `8` into `EBX` (since this was the last thing you pushed), which you don't care about. The next pop puts the original value of `EAX` back into `EBX` (the first thing you pushed), which you then go on to use later.

If you didn't care about preserving any of the values being popped off of the stack, you could simply use an ADD instruction, adding 8 bytes to the stack pointer:

```
add esp, 8
```

This is probably slightly faster than two pops, but it is actually slightly larger (3 bytes instead of 2 bytes, [as Jester points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246596/what-is-this-assembly-code-is-doing/38247037#comment63914981_38246596)) Sometimes optimizing for code size is just as important as optimizing for code speed, since when the code is smaller, more of it can fit into the cache. But in this case, I suspect the more important concern was obtaining the first value that was pushed. Since malloc takes only one parameter, the only reason for the first push was to preserve the original value of `EAX`, since it is clobbered by the function call (functions return their result in `EAX`). Therefore, an alternative way to write the code would have been:

```
; Save EAX by moving it into a caller-save register
; (that will not get clobbered by the malloc function).
mov EBX, EAX

; Call the malloc function by pushing a 4-byte parameter and then rebalancing the stack.
push 8 
call malloc
add  esp, 4

; EAX contains malloc's return value, and EBX contains the original value of EAX
; that we saved before calling malloc.
mov [EAX],   0
mov [EAX+4], EBX
```

Comment: Some of your comments in code blocks say 8 bytes for each push/pop.

Comment: @peter Oh, they actually all do. I guess I just liked typing 8. Fixed now.

Comment: The extra push/pop change the stack alignment.  Depending on the ABI, `esp` might need to be 16byte-aligned before a `call` (e.g. i386 SysV).  On Intel CPUs with a stack engine (Pentium M and later), using esp directly requires the stack engine to insert an extra uop to sync the value in the out-of-order core with its offset.  So if load/store port throughput isn't an issue, push/pop can actually be a cheaper way to align the stack.  clang does this even at `-O3` (not just `-Os`), but pops into a dummy register.  This style, of actually saving/restoring with push/pop, adds latency to EBX.

Comment: It is also important to note that `cdecl` is one of several possible so-called "calling conventions," all of which have to do with exactly how the stack is managed (and, by whom), and how parameters are passed to-and-from functions. You must know what convention the called-library is using, and you must conform to it exactly. Naturally, a compiler does the dirty-work for you, as long as you correctly tell the compiler what the convention is.